# How to use the DjangoCommands package in Sublime Text

Tags: python, django, sublimetext3

I'm trying to use the DjangoCommands package to run Django commands directly in Sublime Text. I read the doc [here](https://github.com/vladimirnani/DjangoCommands#django) but I can't find a way to use any commands.

I tried a lot of combinaison in the Sublime's console and in my REPL interpreter like

```
django_shell
Django: Shell
manage.py shell
```

but nothing works.

Do anyone knows where and how I can use the commands provide with this package ?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the command palette "Ctrl+shift+p" and search "Django:", remember to set the paths to your virtualenv directories so the plugin can work correctly.

Comment: Can you tell us how to set the paths to the virtualenvs ? Where and how in the settings ? How far in the path should we go (to the virtualenv root ? to bin/ ?) ? Thanks